# Autoplay video on lity.js popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a gallery of video thumbnails that each have an overlay called .video-overlay that calls a lity.js popup with a dynamic video.

When the video loads in a popup I want it to start playing automatically.

Here is the page with the videos formosapark-hotel.com/hotel-info/video-gallery/

I have tried so many things but I cannot even get an event to fire when the popup loads.

Even if I can get a simulated click on the round button on the video that is displayed on the popup.

Any pointers is really appreciated as I have been stuck on this for hours.

This is the code of the html button that fires the video, is there a way of executing this button from jQuery?

```
<div class="jw-icon jw-icon-display jw-button-color jw-reset" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Start Playback"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="jw-svg-icon jw-svg-icon-buffer" viewBox="0 0 240 240" focusable="false"><path d="M120,186.667a66.667,66.667,0,0,1,0-133.333V40a80,80,0,1,0,80,80H186.667A66.846,66.846,0,0,1,120,186.667Z"></path></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="jw-svg-icon jw-svg-icon-replay" viewBox="0 0 240 240" focusable="false"><path d="M120,41.9v-20c0-5-4-8-8-4l-44,28a5.865,5.865,0,0,0-3.3,7.6A5.943,5.943,0,0,0,68,56.8l43,29c5,4,9,1,9-4v-20a60,60,0,1,1-60,60H40a80,80,0,1,0,80-79.9Z"></path></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="jw-svg-icon jw-svg-icon-play" viewBox="0 0 240 240" focusable="false"><path d="M62.8,199.5c-1,0.8-2.4,0.6-3.3-0.4c-0.4-0.5-0.6-1.1-0.5-1.8V42.6c-0.2-1.3,0.7-2.4,1.9-2.6c0.7-0.1,1.3,0.1,1.9,0.4l154.7,77.7c2.1,1.1,2.1,2.8,0,3.8L62.8,199.5z"></path></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="jw-svg-icon jw-svg-icon-pause" viewBox="0 0 240 240" focusable="false"><path d="M100,194.9c0.2,2.6-1.8,4.8-4.4,5c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0H65c-2.6,0.2-4.8-1.8-5-4.4c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6V45c-0.2-2.6,1.8-4.8,4.4-5c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0h30c2.6-0.2,4.8,1.8,5,4.4c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6V194.9z M180,45.1c0.2-2.6-1.8-4.8-4.4-5c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0h-30c-2.6-0.2-4.8,1.8-5,4.4c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6V195c-0.2,2.6,1.8,4.8,4.4,5c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0h30c2.6,0.2,4.8-1.8,5-4.4c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6V45.1z"></path></svg></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I inspect your code i find this

```
<div id="video-overlay" style="cursor: pointer;margin-top:-183px;z-index:1;position:relative;height:150px;width:270px;margin-bottom:20px" href="#" data-lity="" data-lity-target="//media.videopolis.com/1.0/api/getById/eng/7b7638244aa2e970c94307f37c95187767354c3c.html?key=1a917ba295a7fb07&amp;autoplay=false&amp;mute=true&amp;autoreplay=false&amp;playlist=false&amp;volume=30&amp;mouseOverMode=false&amp;blank="></div>
```

I suppose if you change autoplay=false to autoplay=true, you will get what you wish.

Comment: Hi Lazar, problem with making that parameter equal to true results in the video  thumbnails playing on page load whereas I only wish to play the video when the user clicks the thumbnail.

Comment: e.g thebuenaventurahotel.com/gallery.html

Comment: adding the following attributes autoplay preload="auto" muted does not work either

Comment: The simplest fix was to create two Urls in server side code one for the thumbnail that has autoplay=false the other has autoplay=true.

Comment: Thanks Lazar much appreciated.